# Problem with drawing SVG rectangle in blazor

Tags: image, svg, coordinates, blazor, rect

I have a problem with drawing svg rectangle on image on Offset Y.
It alwys draw from 0 but not from the pointer position.

I want to draw rectangle in some parts of image and save coordinates to OCR only those elements.

```
<img width="800" height="700"
     @onpointerdown=PointerDown @onpointerdown:preventDefault
     @onpointerup=PointerUp @onpointerup:preventDefault
     @onpointermove=PointerMove @onpointermove:preventDefault
     src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg"
     style="position:absolute;z-index:1;"
     />
@if (myRect.display)
{
    <svg width="800" height="700" style="position: absolute; z-index: 2;"
     @onpointerdown=PointerDown @onpointerdown:preventDefault
     @onpointerup=PointerDown @onpointerup:preventDefault
     @onpointermove=PointerMove @onpointermove:preventDefault
     >
         <rect x="@myRect.x" y="@myRect.y" width="@myRect.width" height="@myRect.height" style="fill:transparent;stroke-width:2;stroke:rgb(255,0,0)" />
     </svg>
 }

@code{
    public class rect
    {
        public bool display { get; set; }
        public double x { get; set; }
        public double y { get; set; }
        public double width { get; set; }
        public double height { get; set; }
    }
    rect myRect = new rect();
    bool mouseDown = false;
    Task PointerDown(PointerEventArgs e)
    {
        mouseDown = true;
        myRect.display = true;
        myRect.x = e.OffsetX;
        myRect.y = e.OffsetY;
        myRect.width = e.Width;
        myRect.height = e.Height;
        StateHasChanged();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    Task PointerUp(PointerEventArgs e)
    {
        mouseDown = false;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    Task PointerMove(PointerEventArgs e)
    {
        if (mouseDown)
        {
            myRect.width = e.OffsetX - myRect.x;
            myRect.height = e.OffsetY - myRect.y;
            StateHasChanged();
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7SGl.jpg)
What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Only quickly glanced your code.. isn't it ``clientX`` and not ``offsetX``

Comment: I try that way and it didnt work to :|